# Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of String What is wrong with the ()'s?

Tags: vb.net, string

```
Private Sub radioButton2_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles radioButton2.CheckedChanged
        Dim words As New String("word1", "word2", "word3")
        Dim randomword = GenerateWord(words)
```

and the Function

```
Public Function GenerateWord(Byval words As String()) As String
    Return words(New System.Random().Next(0, words.Length + 1))
End Function
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this? Any help?

The error is this code:

```
Dim randomword = GenerateWord(words)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `Option Strict` to `On`, then that would not even compile. However, `words` is a string not a string-array. You want:

```
Dim words As String() = {"word1", "word2", "word3"}
```

I must admit that i don't even understand how the VB.NET compiler creates a `Char()` from `New String("word1", "word2", "word3")` for the [string constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx), a very weird implicit conversion.